# Increasing size of varchar shows normal but will not allow the extra size

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

We have a SQL Server 2012.

I did not build the database it goes with a custom made GUI. The GUI links to many databases(I do not have access to any of the DBs other than mine) and each new database is basically a subdomain of information and created identically. I was given rights for a short time to change a field size from varchar 10 to 50 and used:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN column name VARCHAR (50)
```

In MSSMS it shows varchar(50) however when I try to enter anything larger than 10 I get a `String or binary data would be truncated` error

I am not sure where to go from here and cannot understand why it will not allow larger than 10 if its seen as 50?

@dfundako If I attempt to insert '123456789' it works, if I try '12345678901234567890' it will error

Thanks

Comment: What is an example value you're trying to input?

Comment: Any triggers on the table that still use the shorter data type, insert or update columns or call any functions that do so? Or calculated columns? Some weird check constraint maybe?

Comment: @sticky bit none that I can find but maybe I am not looking in the right area?

Comment: `select name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) from sys.triggers where parent_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tablename')` and `select name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) from sys.check_constraints where parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tablename')`

Comment: Make sure you've connected to the right database.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this.

Thanks to @Charlieface.

It was a trigger found using

```
select name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) 
from sys.triggers 
where parent_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tablename')
```

That trigger was interrupting the inserts into that table and keeping a record of changes to that column in another table.

I increased the size of that table's (one keeping track of changes) column, and the problem was solved.

Thanks:)